# Is asking a question to settle a bet acceptable on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, bad-questions

Referring to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55744350/i-am-trying-to-run-a-typeof-function-but-it-is-throwing-an-error) question which was asked on the 18th of April 2019 (yesterday).

The user had a query regarding some JavaScript keyword. Turns out that this was not a problem but a bet which the OP had with his friend. This practice is gambling but we didn't know about it, because the OP posted the comment after we had helped him and left the question. I believe this incident wasted the time of the user who answered below and other people who commented some references (including me).

What should we do about it? Should we allow people to ask questions that they know the answer to just to bet about if the people on Stack Overflow can answer it?

Comment: It doesn't matter what prompted the question. If the question is of good enough quality and is on topic for the site, it is acceptable to be posted. If it is not, then we have the normal actions of voting and closing.

Comment: The circumstances surrounding a question having been posted are irrelevant. If the question is on topic, it’s on topic.

Comment: They are @Clive but what if these practices prompted more circumstances like these?

Comment: People would we wasting their time on useless questions which the op knew the answer to but they want the people on SO to figure it out

Comment: @window.document: so how would you propose we stop people from using that as a motivation to post questions, and how are our current mechanisms (voting and closing) not sufficient?

Comment: If the circumstances prompted more good questions to be asked, whose reason for posting we still don’t care about? Yes please, that would be great

Comment: @window.document: and again, what if a bet leads to a great question being posted? How would you handle that case, assuming we can even prove that there actually was a bet involved?

Comment: The fact that a bet inspired the question isn't relevant. It doesn't matter... Judge the question on its own (lack of) merits.

Comment: The question look Of topics. Take any code, add invisible char => Great a valid question!

Comment: That's not the first iteration of those kind of trick questions. I'ù pretty sure it also has it's own meta dupe somewhere

Comment: Note the they were not "gambling on Stack Overflow"; they were using Stack Overflow as a basis of a gamble. A bit of semantics, but important. People bet on everything, presidential elections, whether someone dies (is Abe Vagoda alive?), etc.

Comment: I see no gambling in this question. Only one user that claim that he win money trying to trick SO "_Thanks to you i got 10 bucks!_". 1rst it's only a claim. 2nd the comment doesn't help the question or add detail or anything, It's really not usefull. If I had post a comment saying "Thanks to your answer, I got a [banana]" will someone post a meta question about "Is it legal to use SO as banana provider? "

Comment: @window.document in your example, it's a clear typo, so it should have been closed and makes no sense to be opened. If someone asked a clear, on topic question.... why is it bad that someone had a bet on the question?

Comment: @MartijnPieters i never talked about anyone's intent. I thought by judging the quality of the question and the comment about the bet being made. If a bet triggers a great question, then it is well received by the community, if a bet triggers a question that is off-topic then this should be stopped, The comment made me a little angry. It was totally un-professional. It was good till the user asked and moved on.

Comment: Okay, now you owe me a dollar. I lost the bet that no-one would dare to bring that bet-question to meta ...

Comment: @window.document: then **what are you asking for here**? It doesn't matter if we think 'gambling' or 'bets' are acceptable. We can't even begin to act even if there was a consensus that such motivations were to be unacceptable. All that matters (and all that we have influence over) is whether or not the question being asked is good or bad.

Comment: If we allowed this on SO then more question will arise as duplicated, off topic and irrelevant because the op will know the answer to it but will ask the community instead just for their fun?

Comment: @window.document: because you do actually talk about intent, your last sentence is **exactly** about intent: *Should we allow people to ask questions that they know the answer to just to bet about if the people on Stack Overflow can answer it*. If they post a question just to see if someone can answer it because they can then win a bet, that's an intent. A motivation to post a question. How do you propose we are going to vet questions based on the motivations, the intent, of the person posting it?

Comment: @window.document But do we allow duplicates? no, we don't. We close them as duplicates. Why do you think this is "acceptable"? We are telling you "we don't care if it's a bet, as long as it's a good question and ok and is on topic". Your examples are clearly not that... so they should be closed.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I think the motivation of OP is irrelevant. The question should be moderated like any other question: on its own merit.

Whether it comes from a bet or not doesn't change anything. If it were a very good question, should we consider it any differently because of the intention of the asker?

More importantly, there is absolutely nothing we can do about people's thoughts, we're not psychics. If they consistently lose bets and post bad questions, they'll get banned anyway.